# JFreeChart setTickLabelFont() and setLabelFont() not working with iText PDF

Tags: java, fonts, import, itext, jfreechart

I'm trying to set the font of my chart's x-axis in this manner:

```
CategoryPlot plotCat =  (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
CategoryAxis xAxis = plotCat.getDomainAxis();
Font font = new Font("SanSerif", Font.STRIKETHRU, 3);
//or Font font = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 3, Font.BOLD);
xAxis.setTickLabelFont(font);
//or xAxis.setLabelFont(font);
```

This is the solution that I keep reading about but it doesn't work for me. I keep getting the messages: `The method setTickLabelFont(Font) in the type Axis is not applicable for the arguments (Font)` and `The method setLabelFont(Font) in the type Axis is not applicable for the arguments (Font)`.

What is going on that is not allowing me to apply a different font to these labels?

It's possible that it's because I'm importing `com.itextpdf.text.Font` instead of `java.awt.Font`, but `com.itextpdf.text.Font` is necessary to set the font of other elements in the PDF. How do I resolve these differences if this is indeed the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JFreeChart requires java.awt.Font.  If you are already importing com.itextpdf.text.Font in your source file, then you'll have to use the fully qualified class name to create a Font for JFreeChart, for example:

```
java.awt.Font font = new java.awt.Font(Font.SERIF, Font.PLAIN, 10);
```

Comment: Perfect! I couldn't figure out how to import `java.awt.Font` on just one line. Thank you!